# App de musica não roda no Android

Tags: android, android-studio

Olá eu estava criando um app de musica cuja  eu aperto o botão toque a musica, eu copilei todo código e fui executar o programa não depurou no meu celular e abri da um erro em seguida abre  uma tela  do executável de musica do próprio pc e começa a tocar no pc a musica.

imagens

[image: imagem do erro e do código]

[image: imagem que mostra a musica na pasta raw]
[image: mostra depois queda o erro abre a music no pc]

> código usado

```
package imperiogamerplay.music;

    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button bt;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    bt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttons);
    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.Starboy);
    bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public  void  onClick(View view) {
            mp.start();
        }
    });

}

}
```

Comment: Ele esta dizendo que o nome do arquivo deve ser em caixa baixa, ou seja tudo minusculo!

Comment: Mesmo eu colocando menusculo ele da este tipo de erro  o de baixo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, o arquivo de áudio não aceita letras maiúsculas ou caracteres especiais, renomeie seu arquivo para starboy.mp3 e faça o teste.

Rode diretamente no celular ou através de emulador

Comment: Obrigado erro simples falta de atenção minha . Mas mt obrigado